# Filtering results from AJAX checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have a few checkboxes on the front end of my system whereby the user checks the boxes to filter results from the database results. There are 6 checkboxes.

In the database, each profile can have one or more of these checkbox values assigned to them, so by clicking a checkbox the user is filtering through many profiles and each one has to contain the checkboxes that are currently ticked.

My problem is that I have it half working, but cant quite seem to figure out the logic about how to finish it. There still seems to be values in there that dont match:

```
        $pieces = explode(", ", $row['competency']);
        foreach(array_keys($_POST['competencyFilter']) as $filter){ //each chosen
            if(in_array($filter, $pieces)){ //if this chosen is in the db
                if(in_array($row['ID'], $resultList)){
                }else{
                    $resultList[] = $row['ID'];
                }
            }else{
                if(($key = array_search($row['ID'], $resultList)) !== false) {
                    unset($resultList[$key]);
                }
                //continue 2;
            }   
        }
```

Iam not sure if the logic here is too complicted for what I want, but at the moment it loops through all the values that are currently ticked in checkboxes, and for each one, if it exists in a profile, it adds the profile ID to an array.

The problem is that some profile ID's remain in the final array $resultList[] even when a tickbox is ticked that isnt in that profile.

I hope this makes sense...

EDIT

Here is the array data in each profile stored in the DB (obviously will contain different values for each profile, but there are 6 all together):

thermXMbb, thermXPbb, thermXMrf, thermXPrf, .. , ..

There are 6 all together, and there are also 6 checkboxes, one for each of these.

Comment: Could you please add array data in above question? That will be helpful

Comment: I am trying to understand the issue so please bear with me.
array `$pieces` is equal to `Array ( [0] => thermXMbb [1] => thermXPbb [2] => thermXMrf [3] => thermXPrf [4] => .. [5] => .. )`
and what is structure of `$_POST['competencyFilter']` and `$row['ID']`

Comment: array_keys($_POST['competencyFilter']) contains an array of whatever is currently checked. These values are the same as the ones in $pieces. The $row['ID'] is the profile ID of the matched profile int he database which the column containing the values SHOULD contain all values that have been checked.

Comment: I may be wrong but if `$pices` is equal to what I have added in above comment and `$_POST['competencyFilter']` is  exactly equal to it then I guess `$filter` will have `numeric value` so ` if(in_array($filter, $pieces)){` may not work correctly. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I believe it does compare correctly asI want it too as I can see results in var_dump. However, I think the problem is something to do with the fact that if I tick some checkboxes, and then untick the ones I ticked at the beginning, there are still profiles in the final array that shouldnt be there. It's as it they're not being deleted properly if they do not exist in the check box array